# 'No values given for wildcard error' in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to make a simple pipeline using snakemake to download two files from the web and then merge them into a single output.

What I thought would work is the following code:

```
dwn_lnks = {
    '1': 'https://molb7621.github.io/workshop/_downloads/sample.fa',
    '2': 'https://molb7621.github.io/workshop/_downloads/sample.fa'       
    }
import os

# association between chromosomes and their links
def chromo2link(wildcards):
    return dwn_lnks[wildcards.chromo]

rule all:
    input:
        os.path.join('genome_dir', 'human_en37_sm.fa')

rule download:
    output:
        expand(os.path.join('chr_dir', '{chromo}')),
    params:
        link=chromo2link,
    shell:
        "wget {params.link} -O {output}"


rule merger:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join('chr_dir', "{chromo}"), chromo=dwn_lnks.keys())
    output:
        os.path.join('genome_dir', 'human_en37_sm.fa')
    run:
        txt = open({output}, 'a+')
        with open (os.path.join('chr_dir', "{chromo}") as file:
                    line = file.readline()
                    while line:
                        txt.write(line)
                        line = file.readline()
        txt.close()
```

This code returns the error:
`No values given for wildcard 'chromo'. in line 20`

Also, in the merger rule, the python code within the run does not work.

The tutorial in the snakemake package does not cover enough examples to learn the details for non-computer scientists. If anybody knows a good resource to learn how to work with snakemake, I would appreciate if they could share :).

Comment: `link=chromo2link` is the error I think. `chromo2link`is a function and expects a wildcard as a parameter

Comment: No, this is fine. Passing function names is a way to execute code that is conditional on wildcard values in Snakemake. Snakemake will call that function with a wildcards object, and the function can return the thing it looks up in the dictionary.

Comment: By asking questions here, you are currently contributing to create a learning resource for snakemake. Hopefully these stackoverflow questions and answers will help others in the future. Keep asking if you can, and if you find answers by yourself, you might also want to share the problem and the solution here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have an `expand` function in the output of the rule `download` that does not define the value for the wildcard `{chromo}`. I guess what you really want here is

```
rule download:
output:
    'chr_dir/{chromo}',
params:
    link=chromo2link,
shell:
    "wget {params.link} -o {output}"
```

without the `expand`. The `expand` function is only needed to **aggregate** over wildcards, like you do it in the rule `merger`.

Also have a look at the official Snakemake tutorial, which explains this in detail.