# snakemake wildcards for parallel rule

Tags: parallel-processing, wildcard, snakemake

I am attempting to input a variable parameter to a python script that takes the same input file but will create different output files. I would like the rule to execute in parallel for any parameter I supply. For example:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "merged.txt"

rule run_foo:
    input:
        "input_file"
    output:
        expand("output_{chrm}.txt")
    shell:
        """
        python script.py {input} {wildcards.chrm} {output}
        """

rule merge_output:
    input:
        expand("output_{chrm}.txt", chrm=range(1,3))
    output:
        "merged.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

There is probably a few things incorrect in this example, but the idea is to show an example of my issue creating a pipeline that can run `run_foo` in parallel to create the `output_{chrm}.txt` files, and then concatenate all of those with `merge_output`.

Comment: this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702238/no-values-given-for-wildcard-error-in-snakemake

I have tried removing `expand()` from `run_foo` `output`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `expand` in the `rule run_foo`:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        "merged.txt"

rule run_foo:
    input:
        "input_file"
    output:
        #expand("output_{chrm}.txt")
        "output_{chrm}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        python script.py {input} {wildcards.chrm} {output}
        """

rule merge_output:
    input:
        expand("output_{chrm}.txt", chrm=range(1,3))
    output:
        "merged.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: I posted my comment the same time you added this answer, however I was mistaken. the error in my real rule (not this toy example) when I removed `expand` had to do with not escaping a wildcard in `expand` like so: `expand({{study}}/output_{chrm}, chrm=range(1,3)`. this answers the question as posted though. thank you!